# Unix command (other than 'stat' and 'ls') to get file modification date without parsing

Tags: file, unix, last-modified

I am writing a shell script in which I have to find the last modification date of a file.

`Stat` command is not available in my environment.

So i am using `'ls'` as below to get desired result.

```
ls -l filename | awk '{print $6 $7 $8}'
```

But I have read in many forums that [parsing `ls` is generally considered bad practise](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). While it (probably) works fine most of time, it's not guaranteed to work everytime.

Is there any other way to get file modification date in shell script.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about using the `find` command?

e.g.,

```
 $ find filenname -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\n"
```

This particular format string gives output like this: `2012-06-13 00:05`.

The [find man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) shows the formatting directives you can use with `printf` to tailor the output to what you need/want. Section `-printf format` contains all the details.

Compare `ls` output to `find`:

```
$ ls -l uname.txt | awk '{print  $6 , "", $7}'
2012-06-13  00:05

$ find uname.txt -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM\n"
2012-06-13 00:05
```

Of course you can write scripts in any number of languages such a Python or Perl etc, to get the same information, however asking for a "*unix command*" sounded as if you were looking for a "built-in" shell command.

**EDIT**:

You could also inovke Python from the command line like this:

```
$ python -c "import os,time; print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('uname.txt'))"
```

or if combined with other shell commands:

```
$ echo 'uname.txt' | xargs python -c "import os,time,sys; print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(sys.argv[1]))"
```

both return: `Wed Jun 13 00:05:29 2012`

Comment: If `stat` isn't available, there is a good chance `find -printf` option isn't either. `stat` isn't a standard Unix command while `-printf` is a Gnu extension.

Comment: @jlliagre well, hopefully OP will let us know if this is a workable solution or not. If not, we can think of other options.

Comment: OSX (10.9): We have stat but no printf.

Answer (score 6):

depending on your OS you could just use

```
date -r FILENAME
```

The only version of unix this doesn't appear to work on is Mac OS, where according to the man files, the -r option is :

```
 -r seconds
         Print the date and time represented by seconds, where seconds is
         the number of seconds since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1,
         1970; see time(3)), and can be specified in decimal, octal, or
         hex.
```

instead of

```
   -r, --reference=FILE
          display the last modification time of FILE
```

Comment: `date -r` is not available on OS X  :(

Answer (score 4):

Do you have perl?

If so, you can use its built-in `stat` function to get the mtime (and other information) about a named file.

Here's a small script that takes a list of files and prints the modification time for each one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my @stat = stat $file;
    if (@stat) {
        print scalar localtime $stat[9], " $file\n";
    }
    else {
        warn "$file: $!\n";
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./mtime.pl ./mtime.pl nosuchfile
Tue Jun 26 14:58:17 2012 ./mtime.pl
nosuchfile: No such file or directory
```

The `File::stat` module overrides the `stat` call with a more user-friendly version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $stat = stat $file;
    if ($stat) {
        print scalar localtime $stat->mtime, " $file\n";
    }
    else {
        warn "$file: $!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILE=./somefile.txt

modified_at=`perl -e '$x = (stat("'$FILE'"))[9]; print "$x\n";'`

not_changed_since=`perl -e '$x = time - (stat("'$FILE'"))[9]; print "$x\n";'`

echo "Modified at $modified_at"
echo "Not changed since $not_changed_since seconds"
```