# How can I get the created/modified date of a file in Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell, unix

How can I get the created/modified date of a file in Shell Scripting ?

```
e.g: if we use ls -lrt <file path/name>
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tos.tls tos 7140612 Nov 15 15:27 result_file_Nov1513_15:23:49
```

is there any way to get the created date (YYYY-MM-DD) of a file without doing text processing for above output (using a direct command) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix command (other than 'stat' and 'ls') to get file modification date without parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216094/unix-command-other-than-stat-and-ls-to-get-file-modification-date-without)

Answer (score 12):

Use `stat`:

```
stat -c %w filename
```

Note that the date shown in your `ls` example is not the create date but the last modified date, which you'd get with stat formatter `%y` instead:

```
stat -c %y filename
```

Comment: It's in the GNU coreutils.  (the one `cat`, `ls` and `tr` come from)  What kind of a distribution do you have that doesn't have `stat`?

Comment: For the record, `stat -f %B` is the OS X command for when the inode was created.

Answer (score -1):

For this I would try the code below:
Try: ls -la | grep filename
Let me know if it works